# Grails not using message.properties for Errors messages?

Tags: spring, grails, localization, groovy, internationalization

I'm trying to get at the localized form of a simple error code, but I can't seem to get it to parameterize as it should. In my integration test, I have this, just to illustrate the issue:

```
for( FieldError error : errors.fieldErrors )
{
    println error.toString()
}
```

In some manual binding, I have this:

`myObject.errors.rejectValue("field1.field2", "typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer", [value] as Object[], "")`

But when I print I get this:

```
Field error in object 'com.me.MyObject' on field 'field1.field2': rejected value [1];   
codes   
[typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer.com.me.MyObject.field1.field2,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer.field1.field2,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer.field2,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer.int,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer]
```

Why doesn't the string from `message.properties` get used?
`typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=Property {0} must be a valid number`

Comment: `"field1.field2"` reference makes me doubt - is it a valid field reference? Is it a nested field? We use just `"field2"`, for instance.
Besides that, absolutely similar code works for me.
Do you have `typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer` message explicitly in your `messages.properties`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<g:message>` tag as ataylor has suggested or the [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage%28org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable,%20java.util.Locale%29) Spring bean defined by Grails. An example of using this in a controller is shown below

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU

class SomeController {

  MessageSource messageSource

  def someAction = {SomeObject someObject ->

    for (error in someObject.errors) {

      // lookup the error message
      Locale locale = RCU.getLocale(request)
      String errorMsg = messageSource.getMessage(error)

      println errorMsg
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass your error through the `g:message` tag to get the message from `message.properties`.  In a controller, you can write something like this:

```
for( FieldError error : errors.fieldErrors )
{
    println g.message(error: error)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `messageSource` spring bean:

```
def messageSource

for( FieldError error : errors.fieldErrors )
{
    def locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
    println messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
}
```

Comment: +1 Seems like you updated your answer with the Spring bean info just as I was posting mine. I'm tempted to delete mine, but I'll leave it for now, as I think it adds some very marginal extra details